# Why does "merge by distance" not work here?

Tags: modeling

I'm using blender 2.92 and trying to apply "merge by distance" on a mesh.[image] You can see in the gif that I first select the vertex to show it is overlapped, then "merge by distance". I expect that after the "merge by distance" was applied I would end up with only one vertex but we can see that nothing changes after I apply it.

For context, I created the mess by starting with a cube, scaling on the X axis then I scaled the two sides to 0 on the x axis to create an edge shape so at that point there are two edges overlapped. I'm guessing it has something to do with how I attempted to create the edge on this mesh?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have not selected both vertices to be merged. One is 'In Front' of the other, so hiding it from selection.

You have 2 options:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, toggle into X-ray mode in the viewport, so the back vertex is no longer hidden when making the selection

or

- Check 'Unselected' in the operator's <kbd>F9</kbd> *Adjust Last Operation* panel, which will merge selected vertices to all others within the given distance, selected or not.

[image]

Comment: Right, it works that way. However why does it not if I select everything with A and then F3 > "Merge by distance"? Seems it does work if I view it in wireframe mode

Comment: @IustinianOlaru If **A** followed by *Merge by Distance* isn't working, your threshold is probably too low. Also, the tool should work the same no matter what shading mode you're in. ;)

Comment: Another potential problem is scale. If your scale is for example 0.001, then whilst your threshold distance may seem OK, the scale could be stuffing it up.