# delete 16 vertices that are on top of each other

Tags: vertices

I looked through the blender forum and tried all the suggestions but none of it worked. My problem is I have 16 vertices that are stacked directly ontop of each other and in order to delete those vertices I have to press the delete key and then select vertices 16 times there are multiple areas where that occurs and it took me about an hour to delete all of the vertices. I want to avoid this in the future as I will be creating many of the same meshes/objects. Does anybody know how I can select and delete the vertices all at the same time instead of pressing delete 16 times?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/222737/35559)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the <kbd>Merge by Distance</kbd> option.

To activate the option, use the shortcut <kbd>M</kbd>, than <kbd>B</kbd> to activate the function.

If any vertices are deleted, you should get a message like the one to the right in the screenshot.

The pie menu to the left in the screenshot are options for the function such as delete by vertices distances (from each other), selected or unselected, etc.

[image]

Comment: I googled that and tried it earlier no matter what settings I using with merge by distance it only removes 1 vertice. Sorry not the answer.

Comment: Did you try selecting or not selecting the mesh vertices?

Comment: I tried every setting

Comment: @calmchess: ok, then provide us with an example blend file, where merge distances doesn't work and we show you how it works.

Comment: I don't know how to add a file here so I put the .blend file on my webserver you can download it by putting the following link in your browser http://calmchess.com/0.zip

Answer (score 1):

I've downloaded your file, hit <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, then <kbd>M</kbd>, *Merge* > *By Distance* and then Blender says: "Removed 2045 vertice(s)". What do you mean by saying you tried "every setting"?

Comment: Thankyou for taking the time to review the file. You failed to leave the puzzle piece intact and only remove the undesirable vertices around the edge.

Comment: @calmchess The puzzle piece looked very intact after doing the merge... but I guess you know better how it looked on my PC. My apologies that I tried it. ‍♂️

Comment: Actually I reread your comment and I see what you did differently than me. Thanks for your time. I just wasn't comprehending what you did differently than me. I appreciate your efforts....forgive me I'm learning blender I'm more dangerous than good at using blender!

Comment: @calmchess As long as you don't blow everything up with a Mantaflow fire simulation, you're not too dangerous  :D